# dockerfile - Unable to connect error

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, docker, zfs

So here's what i have to do: i need to set up some containers automatically using docker. One of them is liek this: Debian Squeeze with limited CPU shares and limited memory (1 cpu share and 512 mb memory),preinstalled apache2,build-essential,php5,mysql-server-5.5,openssh-server and with some ports opened (8000 for Apache and 1500 for MySQL). So i created the following dockerfile :

```
FROM debian:squeeze

MAINTAINER Name < email : >

# Update the repository sources list

RUN apt-get update


# Install apache, PHP, and supplimentary programs. curl and lynx-cur are for debugging the container.
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install apache2 build-essential php5 mysql-server openssh-server libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql php5-gd php-pear php-apc php5-curl curl lynx-cur

# Enable apache mods.
RUN a2enmod php5
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Manually set up the apache environment variables
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid

EXPOSE 80

# Copy site into place.
ADD www /var/www/site

# Update the default apache site with the config we created.
ADD apache-config.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

# By default, simply start apache.
CMD /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND

#CMD [ "mysqladmin -u root password mysecretpasswordgoeshere"]

EXPOSE 3306
```

the content of apache-config.conf is this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/site

  <Directory /var/www/site/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

and in www folder i put a php file with this code:

```
<?php
        $connect=mysql_connect("localhost:1500","root","") or die("Unable to Connect");
?>
```

to test the connection to the mysql server

then

i build all this into an image like this:

```
sudo docker build --rm --tag="tag_name" .
```

and then i run the image like this

```
sudo docker run -c=1 -m="512m" --net=bridge -p 8000:80 -p 1500:3306 -d --name="container_name" tag_name
```

It seems to work,the apache server works when i access localhost:8000/site in my browser but is shows "Unable to connect". what am i doing wrong?
And another problem is that,the contaienr is running but i can't attach to it.I run this command

```
sudo docker attach CONTAINER_ID
```

and then nothing happens,can't do anythign else from there,What am i doing wrong?

I have to build few more dockerfiles similar to this to create containers.All those must be hosted on a ZFS file system and i have to configure a container repository of 50gb based on it,what does this mean and how do i do that?

I'm sorry for my english,it's not my native language :(
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### MySQL issue

in the PHP code

```
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost:1500","root","") or die("Unable to Connect");
```

`localhost` refers to the container IP address. Since there is no MySQL server running in that container the connection will fail.

In [this gist](https://gist.github.com/thomasleveil/c48e100d819d408f1e58), I've changed a bit your example to have the container start both MySQL and Apache (I assume this was your first intent) using the following instruction: `CMD bash -c '(mysqld &); /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND'` and changed the PHP code to connect to the MySQL server on `localhost:3306`.

### Docker attach

The `docker attach` command is meant to allow you to interact with the process currently running in the foreground of a container. Unless that process is a shell, it won't provide you with a shell in that container.

Take this example:

Start a container running a shell process

```
docker run -it --rm base bash
```

You are now in interactive mode *in* your container and can play around with the shell running in the foreground in that container:

```
root@de8f16a13571:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  selinux  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

if you now exit the shell by typing `exit` the shell process will end, and as that was the process running in the foreground in the container, that container will stop.

`root@de8f16a13571:/# exit
exit
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES`

Now start a new container named `test` running bash again:

```
docker run -it --name test base bash
```

verify you can interact with it and *detach* from it by hitting keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>. You end up back in the docker host shell.

verify that the container named `test` is still running:

`$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
81f0f1094f4a        base:latest         "bash"              6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds                            test`

You can then use the `docker attach` command to attach to the bash program in the container:

```
docker attach test

root@81f0f1094f4a:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  selinux  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

### ZSH

And regarding ZSH, I don't know what all that means either. Also note that having 3 questions at once makes it difficult for the community to come up with a single answer that would answer all 3 ; maybe consider posting a new question for those.

Please comment if my assumptions about how you run MySQL or what your intent is with `docker attach`  are wrong.

Comment: Thanks man,the mysql works now. my intentions with dokcker attach is something like: i have a container running in the background and i want to access it like runing /bin/bash in it's CMD(i hope you understand what you mean). like connecting with SSH at it but without it xD sorry if i'm not making any sense

Comment: I edited my answer to explain what docker attach is for. In your case it would attach to the apache process which will ignore anything you would type in

Comment: ohh i understand,so if i want to run apache and mysql in the background in the cointainer and the last "command" to be the bash so i can access and modify what's in container every time,i mean : Start Apache,Start MySQL then /bin/bash,how can i do that?

Comment: It would not be that simple. The path to follow then is to start your services with [supervisor](http://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/) or using [phusion/baseimage](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker) and have the sshd service running additionally to mysql and apache. This way you could have a shell in the container by connecting with ssh

Comment: you could also give a try to [nsenter](http://www.sebastien-han.fr/blog/2014/01/27/access-a-container-without-ssh/) but I find this tool a bit difficult

Comment: i see,thank you very much for your help. Can i contact you later if i have more questions?`

Comment: you can post questions on stackoverflow and not only me will be able to help you